# How to get average runs for each over in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The first six balls mean first over, next six balls mean second over & so on than how to get average runs for each over.

input as

```
Ball no     Runs
1           4
2           6
3           3
4           2
5           6
6           1
1           2
2           4
3           6
4           3
5           1
6           1 
1           2
```

output should be:

```
Over no  avg runs
1         3.66
2         2.83
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.  I don't see such a column.

Comment: can we use analytical functions with windowing clause?

Comment: The windowing clause is likewise meaningless. You need to provide a way (i.e. a column by which the data can be sorted) to determine which over you're looking at. "The first six balls" is meaningless because SQL tables are unordered. Given the data that you've presented the database *might* **by sheer dumb luck** happen to return the rows in the order you've shown - but because there is no `ORDER BY` clause it is free to return the data in any order it finds convenient. Without an `ORDER BY` you do not have a guarantee of which rows will come first, next, or last.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff suggested, SQL table represents unordered sets, So you have to use an ordered column in your table. If you can use such a column you may use below query -

```
SELECT Over_no  AVG(Runs) avg_runs
FROM (SELECT Ball_no, Runs, CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ORDER_COLUMN, Ball_no) RN / 6) Over_no
      FROM YOUR_TABLE)
GROUP BY Over_no;
```

Comment: Can I use rownum as order column?

Comment: Does your table have only 2 columns?

Comment: YES, Table has only two columns

Comment: Hmm, I think you can add a column as created_date with default value as `SYSDATE` and use that column as ordering.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - only if creating the table took more than one second per row. Otherwise SYSDATE won't help much.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, In oracle, SYSDATE will contain times part also. So this will always work.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - but the resolution of a DATE value in Oracle is only down to one second. So if you create the entire table in less than one second all the rows will have the same date. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e26fc9014d3e52aac16be3beb59139f)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my problem with the following query:

```
SELECT ROWNUM OVER_NO, AVG_RUNS
FROM(
     SELECT ROWNUM RN, 
     ROUND(AVG(RUNS)OVER(ORDER BY ROWNUM RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING),2) AVG_RUNS
     FROM TABLE_NAME
    )
WHERE RN=1 OR RN=7;
```

Comment: . . You only *think* you have solved it.  That this code works is a coincidence and it can stop working at any time.